# in linux kernel, asm or asm-generic?

Tags: linux-kernel

in mm/memory.c, it includes one file:

```
#include <asm/tlb.h>
```

the **tlb.h** is `include/asm-generic/tlb.h` or `arch/arm/include/asm/tlb.h`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If necessary, header files in `arch/arm/include/asm`, will include the corresponding header file in `include/asm-generic`.

So in this instance, `tlb.h` is `arch/arm/include/asm/tlb.h`. And if necessary, it will include `include/asm-generic/tlb.h`.

You can verify this by running the following command:

```
# The memory.s target creates the assembly file for memory.c
make mm/memory.s
```

From that, you can identify which header file is being used.